# Deep Copy of List element and recursion - java

Tags: java, list, deep-copy

I have a `Trade` class with 3 parameters (`amount`, `description`, `date`). The `amount` of each trade cannot be greater than `maxAmount`.

I have many trades saved in a `ListToSend`, and some of the amounts exceed the `maxAmount` limit, so I need to split those trades into multiple trades before sending the list.

I thought about working with two lists, my original `ListToSend` and a `tradesToSplit` list.
Basically I want to:

1. Move each `splitableTrade` from `ListToSend` to `tradesToSplit`.
2. Then I want to loop over `tradesToSplit` and for every trade in there :

   - I call a `recursiveMethod` that is going to divide the amount by 2 and:

     - if `amount/2` is not greater than `maxAmount` :

       - Then I create a `newTrade`, which is essentially a deep copy of the initial trade, and I set the `newTrade` amount to be `originalAmount/2`.
       - if not, I keep dividing the amount by calling `recursiveMethod`

But I'm stuck here as I have no idea how to edit the original trade after many iteration of `recursiveMethod`.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in OOP it is recommended to keep objects immutable because immutable objects are inherently thread-safe, easier to debug (you can share the object reference without worrying about unexpected or unauthorized changes), etc.

In your case I would create a function `splitTrade` that would take a trade of any `amount` and return a list of trade where each `amount` is less than `maxAmount`.

Here is some pseudo java code:

```java
private List<Trade> splitTrade(Trade trade, List<Trade> acc) {
  if (trade.getAmount() > Trade.MAX_AMOUNT) {
    Trade trade1 = new Trade(Trade.MAX_AMOUNT, trade.getDescription(), trade.getDate());
    Trade trade2 = new Trade(trade.getAmount() - Trade.MAX_AMOUNT, trade.getDescription(), trade.getDate());
    acc.add(trade1);
    return splitTrade(trade2, acc);
  } else {
    acc.add(trade);
    return acc;
  }
}

public List<Trade> splitAllTrades(List<Trade> listToSend) {
  return listToSend.stream().flatMap((t) -> splitTrade(t, new ArrayList<Trade>()).stream().toList();
}
```

without the lambda syntax:

```java
public List<Trade> splitAllTrades(List<Trade> listToSend) {
  List<Trade> validTrades = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Trade trade: listToSend) {    
    validTrades.addAll(splitTrade(trade, new ArrayList<Trade>()));
  }
  return validTrades;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm having trouble understanding in detail what the splitAllTrades method does. I tried running in debug to have better understanding but I have an error saying cannot resolve methd toList in Stream. Do you mind rewriting that part without the lambda expression please ?

Comment: @momodjib Stream.toList is Java 16 and upper. I added a version without the lambda syntax, with a plain old for loop

Comment: Ah that's why, I'm required to use java 8 for this task so I couldn't change for a newer version. Awesome thank you very much. It's 100% clear ! I'll try implementing this tonight.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution would be to have a method inside `Trade` that generates a stream of trades that satisfy the criteria:

```
public class Trade {
    ...
    public Stream<Trade> streamLegalTrades() {
        if (amount < maxAmount)
            return Stream.of(this);

        Trade halfTrade = new Trade(amount / 2, ...);
        return Stream.of(halfTrade, halfTrade)
            .flatMap(Trade::streamLegalTrades);
    }
}
```

If you're not familiar with streams then that statement might be a bit confusing. But it essentially produces 2 new trades and then produces a stream of legal trades for each of those.

This then makes it trivial to convert your list of trades:

```
tradeList.stream().flatMap(Trade::streamLegalTrades).toList();
```